# how to return value from a column in csv file based on matching value on different column with bash/shell commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I need help with a bash script that does following:

```
| section | category | description | date      | metric | value    |
| --------| ---------|-------------|-----------|--------|----------|
| y       | testing  |    abc      |03/02/2022 |        |  14845.0 |
| x       | row      |    pqy      | 01/16/2022|        | 12565.0  |
| x       | row      |    xyz      | 02/21/2021|        | 13888.0  |
| x       | row      |    xyz      | 10/04/2020|        | 18160.0  |
```

I want to return the value column in descending order along with the date when I search for description of `xyz` it should only return the values correspond to that and only the highest value related to one date. there can be duplicate dates too.
for example:

```
10/04/2020 18160
02/21/2021 13888
```

In above case I have description of `xyz` and it returns value in descending order along with date.

What I have tried:
I have been stuck on this

```
awk '$2 ~ /xyz/ {print $3}' covid19_cases_demographics_tests_2022-03-21.csv(this is my csv file)
```

Please guide me correct direction with some example where to start as I am new to shell scripting and unix stuff.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the columns you have displayed, you are using the wrong indexes in `awk`

It looks like you are assuming that the first column (section) will be `$0`, 2nd col (category) will be `$1`, 3rd col (description) will be `$2`. But `awk` actually uses `$0` to represent the entire line. So to search on the description column, you would need to use `$3` in the matching logic and `$6` to print from the value column. Assuming that you have a proper csv file (not some other format), you may also need to set the -F option to specify custom field delimiter such as comma. But note that this has an issue where more complex csv files that contain quoted strings will probably still break this.

```
awk -F, '$3 ~ /xyz/ {print $6}' file.csv
```

If you have more complex csv files that have quoted strings which potentiality contain things like spaces and even commas within the strings that are not used as delimiters, then `awk` (as well as `grep` and `sed`) are probably not the best tools for the job. In this case, the `csvtool` utility is context aware and should work better. On Fedora, the utility is part of the `ocaml-csv` package but the package may be named differently on other distros.

In this case, you can write a function to print the column you want, export the function, and then have `csvtool` pass the columns to it. A bit more work but safer if you have more complex fields.

```
function printifcol {
    local descCol="$3";
    local valueCol="$6";
    if [[ "xyz" == "${descCol}" ]]; then
        echo "${valueCol}";                               
    fi                       
}
export -f printifcol;
csvtool call printifcol file.csv
```

In either case, you can pipe the output to the `sort` command with `-r` (reverse) option to get things in descending order:

```
awk -F, '$3 ~ /xyz/ {print $6}' file.csv | sort -r
 
# assumes function was already exported
csvtool call printifcol file.csv | sort -r
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I works great only had to change one thing ```sort -nr``` in the end. I also tried this ```awk -F, '$3 ~ /Cases of COVID-19 in Colorado by Date Reported to the State/ {print $4,$6}' input.csv | sort -k 2nr | head -n 20```  In terms of performance is awk or grep would be better ? I would say faster string search works better with grep.

Comment: Glad it was useul :-) I'm not sure on the performance aspect; you'd probably need to test that with a sample set of your data to get a decent idea. You can use the `time` command to get some metrics there, e.g. `time awk ...` or `time grep ...`. This will run the command following `time` and then print out some timing metrics. By default, it prints time as "real", "user", and "system"; "real" is the indication of the total amount of real time spent. I generally use that metric and ignore the other two. I think for a fair comparison, you need to do grep + sed (e.g `time $(grep ... | sed ...)`

Comment: ^ the reason being that in the above, you have `awk` doing multiple tasks (matching & substitution) whereas `grep` by itself only does the matching part. doing `grep` + `sed` together does add the overhead of piping to another command, but I'm not sure which is overall the better performer. The things I generally use them for have small data sets so I don't normally notice any difference either way.